# mysql sum case not working

Tags: mysql, sum, case

I am working on a mysql query using sum case.  The query works for some of the cases but not for one case.

```
    select orders.orderid, campers.description, dealers.name, orders.act_delivery, 
sum(case orderitems.std 
when 0 then 
    (case when orderitems.price = 0 then retail_price.price * orderitems. qty else  orderitems.price * orderitems.qty end)
when 1 then 
    (case when orderitems.origqty = 0 then 
        0 else 
        (case when orderitems.price = 0 
            then retail_price.price * (orderitems.qty - orderitems.origqty)   
        else  orderitems.price * (orderitems.qty - orderitems.origqty)
        end)
    end) 

when 2 then
    0
else 
    (case when orderitems.deletedprice = 0 then retail_price.price * orderitems. qty else  orderitems.deletedprice * orderitems.qty end)

end) as retail
 from orderitems, orders, dealers, campers, products, retail_price 
 where orderitems.orderid = orders.orderid 
 and orderitems.productid = products.prodid 
 and orderitems.productid =retail_price.prodid
 and orders.dealerid = retail_price.dealer 
 and orders.dealerid = dealers.dealerid 
 and orders.camper = campers.camperid 
 and act_delivery > 0 
 and orderitems.std in (0, 1, 2) 
 and orders.dealerid not in (1, 9, 10, 12,15,16) 
 and spares_od = 0 
 and orders.act_delivery > '2016-10-01' 
 and orders.act_delivery <= '2016-10-31' 
 group by orders.orderid,orders.dealerid, orders.act_delivery order by orders.act_delivery, orders.orderid
```

The problem occurs when orderitems.std = 3.  In either case I cannot get a result.

All other cases appear to be working correctly.

Comment: That statement can be a lot easier to understand if it used the `join` keyword instead of joining via the `where` clause. Anyhow, if it's not working when `orderitems.std = 3` that's an issue with your data that we cannot resolve. Presumably some combination of that plus your other filters results in no data. Strip out all the select junk and instead just select the relevant columns to see what that where clause is fetching.

Comment: @Schwern  You helped me solve my problem.  I am embarrassed to say that I was filtering out records with std = 3.  

and orderitems.std in (0, 1, 2)